# Is it possible to keep enum values when using wsgen?

Tags: java, enums, xsd, wsgen

When I use wsgen on this java file

```
public enum DayCountConventionMethod {
    METHOD_ACTUAL_360("Actual 360"), METHOD_ACTUAL_365("Actual 365");

    private final String value;

    private DayCountConventionMethod(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

---

I get this result in my generated xsd file:

```
<xs:simpleType name="dayCountConventionMethod">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="METHOD_ACTUAL_360"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="METHOD_ACTUAL_365"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Is it possible to keep the values `Actual 360` and `Actual 365`?

Answer (score 0):

The enumeration value is what's defined in the generated XSD file, since it should correspond to the Enum "name". The values you want wouldn't be valid identifiers.